# WKWebView Canvas issue. Links inside canvas aren't doing anything

Tags: html, ios, swift, canvas, wkwebview

I'm having an issue with WKWebview.
I'm loading a canvas from html into the Webview.
This is the link:
https://cdn-factory.marketjs.com/en/color-fill-playable-ad-demo/index.html

it runs perfectly the html game loads and everything seems to be okay, the touch events are working when you play the mini game tough there is a button "install now"
that should open the app store url and when i tap it nothing happens.
On browser it works and i have tried few of those games but nothings works.

Any advise? the webview preference allowjs and allow inline media are set to true.
Aside that i couldn't find any info on it.
Help is appreciated :D thanks !

iOS: 13.4.1
Swift: 5
iPhone xs max

Answer (score 0):

Okay i figured it out.
In case someone will bash into it in the future.

So the webpage used:

```
window.open("http://asdfsadfsda")
```

javascript code to open the url in a new window.

`WKWebview` wont do anything unless you will implement the `WKUIDelegate` and the method

```
webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration,
         for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
         windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView?;
```

another important thing in order to make this method to get called is to set in the webview preferences like this:

```
        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.preferences = preferences
        configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
        
        configuration.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

And then you can handle the new page opening in the delegate method.
If you still want a new window you should create a new webview and return it in the delegate method.

In my case it was to do nothing and just take the url etc..
so i returned nil.

Good luck :)